# CSS как слева от canvas расположить в столбик 3 блока div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Как слева от canvas расположить в столбик 3 блока div?

```css
.q,.w,.e,.r {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fc0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.q {  background-color: red;}
.w {  background-color: green;}
.e {  background-color: #ff11ff;}
.r {  width: auto;  background-color: #ff1155;  display: block;}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="111.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="q">q</div>
    <div class="w">w</div>
    <div class="e">e</div>  
    <canvas class="r" id="canvas" width="1200" height="1000" style="width:300px; height:300px;" ></canvas>   
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: серьёзно? теперь каждое необходимое позиционирование будет отдельным вопросом оформляться? может лучше для начала выучить основы позиционирования css ? или в прошлом вопросе что-то глобально непонятно?

Comment: Предварительный просмотр сломался не "почему-то", а потому что Вы в JS окно вставили CSS разметку.

Comment: @lexxl, ну постепенно так собирает вопросы из ответов, как из конструктора. Взяли [canvas](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596752/178988) и [позиционирование](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596914/178988), теперь надо немного переставить... Когда наберётся достаточно ответов, будет вопрос, как сделать сайт целиком :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div class="container clearfix">
   <div class="qwe">
<div class="q">q</div>
<div class="w">w</div>
<div class="e">e</div>
```

```
.q,.w,.e,.r {
width: 100px;
padding: 10px;
background: #fc0;
/*   position: relative; */
}

.qwe {    float: right;  }

.q {  background-color: red;}

.w {  background-color: green;}

.e {  background-color: #ff11ff;}

.r {  width: auto;
float: left;
background-color: #ff1155;
display: block;
}

.container {
 width: 440px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 }

.clearfix:after {
clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;   /* Хак для IE 6 и 7 */
}
```

[Вот так](http://codepen.io/Tkachenko/pen/BQwjZj)